# C# how to handle null values in a list when importing from an excel worksheet

Tags: c#, excel, list, iformfile

I am importing a worksheet from excel into a sql server localdb using C# and Excelpackage. I have of course got null values in the worksheet, for example on strings and doubles. On doubles I have got normally no issues. How to handle in advance that if there is a null value on workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString(), then insert null into the database context class ?

```
 using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Table_Methode"];
                int totalRows = workSheet.Dimension.Rows;

                List<Methode> methodesList = new List<Methode>();

                for (int i = 2; i <= totalRows; i++)
                {
                    methodesList.Add(new Methode
                    {
                        NomMethode = workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString() == null ? "":workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString()
                    });
                }
                _context.Methode.AddRange(methodesList);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return methodesList;
            }
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code, is there an exception or what's happening?

Comment: You could use the [null conditional operator `?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) - `workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value?.ToString() == null ? "" : …`

Comment: `if (x != null)`...?

Comment: @stuartd thanks, let me test. Jon thanks too, but I prefer to use a ternary operator on 1 line.

Comment: @TropicalViking I mean are you wanting your code to work and be easily readable and maintainable, or are you trying to make your code as small as possible, and not that readable? Up to you.

Comment: @Jon I've got 20+ columns to do man and the excel to c# class nuget package is broken on .net core, that sucks, + i have to actually import the data

Comment: @TropicalViking Have you tried a SQL SSIS package to just import from Excel directly into your tables? You can create a package and define what sheets/columns to import and how to map those to your tables. Save the package, re-run as necessary. Another option is create a small utility class that takes the Sheet name, your Table name, object and a list of properties to map from the cells. Make the method generic and you can re-use it for all 20 tables simply by calling ImportFromExcel ("Table_Methode", "NomMethode", 1); where 1 is the column index of NomMethode.

Comment: @Jon Thanks for all the information Jon. I agree we can do all that. I used Stuartd suggestion and it worked fine :) But yes, to automate, or for many many tables, we need to consider using these tools.

Answer (score 1):

I would just check for null and empty strings before adding:

```
using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(file))
{
    ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets["Table_Methode"];
    int totalRows = workSheet.Dimension.Rows;

    List<Methode> methodesList = new List<Methode>();

    for (int i = 2; i <= totalRows; i++)
    {
        if (workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value != null && workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value != String.Empty)
        {
            methodesList.Add(new Methode
            {
                NomMethode = workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.ToString();
            });
        }
    }

    _context.Methode.AddRange(methodesList);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return methodesList;
}
```

Comment: Except Value is not a string, so you cannot call that workSheet.Cells[i, 1].Value.IsNullOrEmpty()     Value is an object.

Comment: No, because it CAN be a string. An object can be a string or it could be something else. Value can indeed == String.Empty.

Comment: Cells.Value is an Object. That object can be a string or could be an Int32. We don't know the type of it, but we can still compare it to String.Empty.